# The process cannot access the 'xml' file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to update a file. I opened the file and then tried to write the content to it but got the exception:

The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Indent = true;

XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("../../../connString.xml", settings);
writer.WriteStartDocument();
writer.WriteComment("This file is generated by the program.");
writer.WriteStartElement("ConnectionString");

if (ConnType == "SQL Server") {
   writer.WriteAttributeString("ID", "SQL Server");
   writer.WriteAttributeString("DataSource", Convert.ToString(TEServer.EditValue));
   writer.WriteAttributeString("Database", Convert.ToString(TEDatabase.EditValue));
   writer.WriteAttributeString("UserID", Convert.ToString(TEUserID.EditValue));
   writer.WriteAttributeString("Password", Convert.ToString(TEPassword.EditValue));
} else if (ConnType == "Access") {
   writer.WriteAttributeString("ID", "Access");
   writer.WriteAttributeString("DbLocation", Convert.ToString(BtnEditDBLoc.EditValue));
}

writer.WriteEndElement();
writer.WriteEndDocument();

writer.Flush();
writer.Close();
```

I've been looking at some sources said to be close "XmlWriter" but in my coding i have closed, with : writer.Close();

But still occurs the same error.

Is there anything that can help me, please?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you rulled out possibility of "because it is being used by another process."?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379689/identify-process-using-a-file

Comment: I do not have a crystal ball, but your problem was most certainly caused because you where debugging, and you stopped the debugger before it reaches the writer.close() line, no?! This is an huge common case :) !

Comment: In which line you are getting an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use using block for accessing any file from system, as accessing any file create a process in our system, and so it neva allow same file to access by two thread . 
So, to close or exit tht process, alws use using block in C#   , using block alws free the resources u r using in your project

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Any of the writers (XmlWriter, FileWriter, etc.) should be wrapped in a using block so they are disposed of properly:

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Indent = true;
settings.CloseOutput = true; 

using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("../../../connString.xml", settings)) {
   writer.WriteStartDocument();
   writer.WriteComment("This file is generated by the program.");
   writer.WriteStartElement("ConnectionString");

   if (ConnType == "SQL Server") {
      writer.WriteAttributeString("ID", "SQL Server");
      writer.WriteAttributeString("DataSource", Convert.ToString(TEServer.EditValue));
      writer.WriteAttributeString("Database", Convert.ToString(TEDatabase.EditValue));
      writer.WriteAttributeString("UserID", Convert.ToString(TEUserID.EditValue));
      writer.WriteAttributeString("Password", Convert.ToString(TEPassword.EditValue));
   } else if (ConnType == "Access") {
      writer.WriteAttributeString("ID", "Access");
      writer.WriteAttributeString("DbLocation", Convert.ToString(BtnEditDBLoc.EditValue));
   }

   writer.WriteEndElement();
   writer.WriteEndDocument();

   //writer.Flush(); //Flush isn't required--handled by the using block
   //writer.Close(); //close isn't required--handled by the using block
}
```

I also added `settings.CloseOutput = true;` which may be necessary according to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5206032/123723)

Comment: In this case, `settings.CloseOutput` will be ignored since no *Stream* or *TextWriter* object is being passed to *XmlWriter.Create()* -- passing a file path causes the internal stream being closed when *XmlWriter* is being closed. Still, i think the remark about `settings.CloseOutput` should be kept in your answer as it is a valuable reminder regarding general usage of *XmlWriter*.